# Confusion about spark accumulator performed inside actions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

From offical doc we can see that :

> For accumulator updates performed inside actions only, Spark
>   guarantees that each task’s update to the accumulator will only be
>   applied once, i.e. restarted tasks will not update the value. In
>   transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may
>   be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed.

I think it is means that accumulator should be performed inside **actions** only, such as `rdd.foreachPartition()`

Through `rdd.foreachPartition`'s API code in pyspark, I find that `rdd.foreachPartition(accum_func)` is equal to :

```
rdd.mapPartitions(accum_func).mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).mapPartitions(some_add_func).collect()
```

It seems that **accum_func** can run inside **transformations**(rdd.mapPartition) ?

Thanks a lot for any explanin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the node running a partition of a map() operation crashes,
Spark will rerun it on another node and even if the node does not crash but is simply
much slower than other nodes, Spark can preemptively launch a “speculative” copy
of the task on another node, and take its result if that finishes.

Even if no nodes fail,Spark may have to rerun a task to rebuild a cached value that falls out of memory.The net result is therefore that the same function may run multiple times on the same data depending on what happens on the cluster.

Accumulators used in actions, Spark applies each task’s update to each accumulator only once. Thus, if we want a reliable absolute value counter, regardless of failures or multiple evaluations, we must put it inside an action like foreach().

Comment: I hope its fine if we only want to read the value of Accumulator in transformations? For e.g. using an IF condition to execute some logic

`code`if(accumulator1.value() > 0){
 -- do something
}`code`